# How to view other Android devices around you

Tags: android, geolocation

I haven't seen this capability with any android app, nor have I seen anyone ask it.  Is there any way that the Bluetooth or something can be used within your app to see a list of all the other android devices around you?  For example, if my friend is using my app and he is in the same room I can see his device on a list in my app, and he can see mine...

Answer (score 2):

There would have to be something that ties to two devices together, for example being on the same Wifi. As it is there is nothing that broadcasts to other devices that you are there by default. Even Bluetooth requires you to turn on discovery mode, or discoverable mode, and even then it will only stay on for a few minutes. If you wish for two devices to tie together, I am almost sure you could use the Bluetooth, but you would have to go through the normal process of discovery, synchronization, and permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use BT to see what OS any phones around you are using, and they would also have to be set to discoverable.

If you want to make an app, it's possible to construct one where people agree to be located, but that's a voluntary issue, and it would be based on GPS radios in the various phones.  I'm working on an app right now that has this capability, but again, it's something people sign up for so they can be located specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would explore using the [Google Latitude API](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/latitude/) as a possible avenue of exploration, before you reinvent the wheel creating a similar service.